# Perpendicular diagonals of quadrilateral $ABCD$ meet at $O$. Find the angle between lines $AB$ and $DC$, given lengths of $OA$, $OB$, $OC$, $OD$.

Tags: geometry, vectors

A few days ago I was at the math Olympiad and I failed to solve only one rather simple task, it feels like a 9th grade, but I either misunderstand something, or there is something quite interesting hidden there

The problem sounds like this:

> In quadrilateral ABCD the diagonals AC and BD are perpendicular and
> intersect at the point O. It is known that OB = OC = 3, OA = 6, OD =
> 9. Find the angle between lines AB and DC by expressing vectors AB and DC through vectors b = OB and c = OC.

I tried to solve the problem using the relationship between the sides, if vector OC is equal to 3 and vector c, and AO is equal to 6, then vector AO will be equal to 2 vectors c. This method I came to find the angle through the cosine of the formula for the scalar product of vectors, but what was my surprise when nothing normal, such an answer option simply does not exist!
by the way, here are answers:

1. 150°
2. 120°
3. 45°
4. 90°
5. 30°

As a result I tried to solve the problem 10 times but nothing worked, well, can anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Without using vectors, you could set up the coordinate system with $O$ as the origin, calculate those slopes and the difference of their arc tangents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c=\vec{OC}$, $b=\vec{OB}$. Now, $b\perp 
 c$ or in other words $b\cdot c=0$ and
$$\vec{AB}=2c+b$$
$$\vec{DC}=3b+c$$
$$\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{DC}=(2c+b)\cdot(3b+c)=2(c\cdot c)+5(c\cdot b)+3(b\cdot b)$$
$$AB\,DC\,\cos\theta=2OC^2+3OD^2$$
$$\sqrt{3^2+6^2}\sqrt{3^2+9^2}\cos\theta=2\times3^2+3\times3^2$$
$$\cos\theta=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$
$$\theta=45^\circ$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose vertices ABCD appear anticlockwise around the quadrilateral. Take O as origin and put A,b on the positive x,y axes. So A is (6,0), B is (0,3), C is (-3, 0), and D is (0,-9). Then the vector AB is (-6,3) and the vector DC is (-3,9). Their dot product is then 18+27=45; their lengths are $3\sqrt5$ and $3\sqrt{10}$; so the cosine of the angle between them is $\frac{45}{3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\sqrt2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. So the angle is $45^\circ$.

That isn't quite the way the question wants it expressed. In the question's own terms, $OA=-2c$ and $OD=-3b$ so $AB=OB-OA=b+2c$ and $DC=OC-OD=c+3b$. So then $AB\cdot DC=(b+2c)\cdot(c+3b)=3b^2+2c^2$ since $b\cdot c=0$, etc. (Personally, I think working in coordinates is a bit easier in this case.)

(If I have to guess what's gone wrong for you, then my best guess is a sign error somewhere. But without seeing your working, it's hard to be sure.)

Comment: In the first paragraph, you need so called, more Mathjax.